# For which the below fraction refer to?

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

I have got this fraction representation :$$a=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\cdots}}}} $$ but i can't know for which it's refer to , I mixed that with Golden ratio however the fractionof Golden ratio is started with 1+ and that started with 0 , Now how i can get the correct Algebraic equation which refer to that number and what is it ?

Comment: This is $\phi-1=\frac{1}{\phi}$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Comment: I don't really see how it wasn't clear that subtracting $1$ from some expression with a known value gives you exactly that value minus $1$

Comment: sorry for that i didn't get attention to that lol

Answer (score 2):

You can write your expression as $$a=\frac{1}{1+a}$$ which gives the quadratic $a^2+a-1=0$, and so $$a=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$$